# Searching Engine Filters:: precount results for each filter

Tags: mysql, ruby, pivot, crosstab, faceted-search

I'm building a search engine for cars. When viewing the search results, on the left there are filters to make the results more specific. I want to be able to show the sum of results that exist when each filter is set for the selected search.

For example the filters could be:

**Make**
Alfa Romeo (500)
BMW (2330)
....

**Colors**
Black (1000)
White (800)
....

I want to calculate the number in the parenthesis effecient without making tens of selects for that. Any idea how to cache this data or make a special table for that?

Keep in mind that everytime a filter is added the sums have to be re-calculated according to the new results.

You can check an example [here](http://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/search.html?usage=&isSearchRequest=true&editSearch=&lang=en&export=ALSO_EXPORT&sortOption.sortOrder=ASCENDING&damageUnrepaired=ALSO_DAMAGE_UNREPAIRED&sortOption.sortBy=searchNetGrossPrice&scopeId=C&makeModelVariant1.makeId=&maxPrice=&minFirstRegistrationDate=&maxMileage=&fuels=&ambitCountry=&zipcode=)

It's pretty tricky I think..
Thanks a lot for any help!
Dimitris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using the [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) search engine for such advanced functionality.
There are several good Ruby gems for easy integration with Solr, you can find pointers [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolRuby).

Answer (score 2):

strange solution -Solr. 
it is good only when you have dedicated server "just for search engine" -if not(when solr and site will be hosted on same server -performance issue).
More simple solution is standard lucene (solr is an java extenstion to lucene)